# Day count conventions for covered parity theory

Tags: currency

I am calculating implied interest rates using covered interest rate parity theorem.
I am looking at the Australian US currency pair. When evaluating day counts, should I be using Actual/365 for Australia and Actual/360 for US?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenGamma has a good resource for [market conventions](https://quant.opengamma.io/Interest-Rate-Instruments-and-Market-Conventions.pdf).

Comment: That's all I was looking for thanks. Surprisingly hard to find on Google.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, USD libor is based on act/360, AUD on act/365 for currencies.