# Japan day count conventions

Tags: options, futures, currency, forward

I am after a good comprehensive resource on Japanese day count conventions. By that I mean, is actual/360 or actual/365 used for pricing various options, forwards, futures, etc.

Comment: This is probably the same as your earlier question: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8812/currency-forwards-implied-interest-rates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for Japan, act/365 for the domestic market, and act/360 for the euroyen market.

For swaps, fixed leg convention is 6m libor act/365, floating leg, if based on libor, is the 6m rate act/360, if tibor, then the 3m rate act/365.